# focus function working in console but in through the code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a webpage which allows you to enter an IP address(IPv4). I want that whenever user has added 3 numbers in the textbox the focus should automatically be transferred to the next textbox. For that I have given onkeypress event to the textbox and called a JS function and sent an argument to it. Have a look at my code.

```
<input onkeypress="check(this)" type="text" 
id="<?php if($i==1){echo "5";} else {echo "1";} ?>"
class="form-control" placeholder="First Octate"/>
```

Here is the check function

```
function check(element){
    if(element.value.length==2){
        newId= parseInt(element.id) + 1
        document.getElementById(newId.toString()).focus()
    }
}
```

Now if I log the `document.getElementById(newId.toString())` to the console, it is giving me a valid element and if I use focus method with the logged element I am actually able to change the focus. What I can't understand is it is not doing the same thing if done using this function. I am not able to change the focus according to the condition

Comment: Small note: your description mentions 3 numbers but your code is checking for 2. Also, when is `check(element)` even called? During some `onchange` listener connected to the inputs afterwards?

Comment: do you have elements with the same ID in your markup?

Comment: keypress is going to give you the length before the next character is added.

Comment: It may have to do with your use of `this`. Try passing the event and accessing the input's value through that (e.g. event.target.value instead of element.value).

Comment: If the problem is in your client-side code then only show client-side code.  PHP is irrelevant here.  Please update the question with a runnable stack snippet which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You are not getting the focus because of the way the event is working.

Comment: @David it's actually showing a duplicate element ids problem

Comment: The issue is not dgoing to be dupe ids, it is the fact the browser ignores the focus in the keypress event

Comment: yes @epascarello, your suggestion is absolutely right (I even upvoted it). I was just noticing php is still useful (IP address I guess equals 4 text input elements with ID problems)

Comment: Arbitrarily changing focus when a field contains a certain number of characters can lead to sub-par user experience.  Please consider validating the field before changing focus and/or testing how your logic works when the user needs to correct values that were entered incorrectly

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs the check(element) is called when user enters something in the texbox

Comment: @GrafiCode I had elements of the same ID in markup but then I resolved that. So, no there are no elements with same ID in my markup

Comment: @David The php code was for showing that the IDs are not getting repeated and I thought that problem can be in that also. I was unsure, so the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `setTimeout` command to your code:

```js
function check(element){
    if(element.value.length==2){
        newId= parseInt(element.id) + 1
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(newId.toString()).focus()
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<input onkeydown="check(this)" type="text" 
id="1"
class="form-control" placeholder="First octet"/>
<input onkeydown="check(this)" type="text" 
id="2"
class="form-control" placeholder="Second octet"/>
<input onkeydown="check(this)" type="text" 
id="3"
class="form-control" placeholder="Third octet"/>
<input onkeydown="check(this)" type="text" 
id="4"
class="form-control" placeholder="Fourth octet"/>
```

Key events seem to refocus their targets' inputs after they have been fired. This tries to resolve that by waiting until the event has finished being fired, from which it will then focus the next input.

Also, I suggest you use `keydown` instead of `keypress` — the latter is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event).

Comment: This solution works perfect. Can you explain or guide me to a resource that explains this behavior as I am still not able to understand WHY did this happen?

Comment: The MDN Docs for `setTimeout` provide a general explanation of what's happening, but essentially, `setTimeout` fires at the next event cycle, which is when all current events have been dealt with. I assume that focussing in the event seems to be restored after the event fires, and so deferring the focus code to a timeout makes a brief delay and then causes focus. See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your code is the focus is not moving because of the action it takes. You need to add a slight delay

```js
function check(element) {
  if (element.value.length == 2) {
    var newId = parseInt(element.id) + 1
    setTimeout(()=>document.getElementById(newId.toString()).focus(),1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeypress="check(this)" type="text" id="1" />
<input onkeypress="check(this)" type="text" id="2" />
<input type="text" id="3" />
```

You would be better off with keyup event

```js
function check(element) {
  if (element.value.length == 3) {
    var newId = parseInt(element.id) + 1
    document.getElementById(newId.toString()).focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="check(this)" type="text" id="1" />
<input onkeyup="check(this)" type="text" id="2" />
<input type="text" id="3" />
```

Now this code is fine if they are typing, if they paste in a value, you have a whole new problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your events up in a window.load script and use data-attributes to inform your input listener on how many numbers to listen for. Also, if you use type='number' you can ensure you'll get numbers

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let q = document.querySelectorAll('.autofoc');
  q.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('input', e => {
      let l = +e.target.dataset.len
      if (e.target.value.length >= l) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, l)
        e.target.nextElementSibling.focus()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="number" data-len='3' class="form-control autofoc" placeholder="Area code" />
<input type="number" data-len='3' class="form-control autofoc" placeholder="First 3" />
<input type="number" data-len='4' class="form-control autofoc" placeholder="Last 4" />
```